# What is <update handle="customer_account"/>?

Tags: magento2, php, database, layout, xml

What is the Handler?
Can someone explain the below code?

```
<update handle="customer_account"/>
```

or same code like above for example :

```
<update handle="default"/>
```

and how it worked !?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each page on a Magento website has a **handle**. That handle equates to a layout XML file. For example, `<update handle="customer_account"/>` indicates to Magento’s layout system that it should take into account any directives contained within the `customer_account.xml` file. This particular file is used commonly amongst the various pages within the customer’s account in the secure, logged in area.

`default.xml` provides layout updates common to all pages on the site.

So, to tie it all together, the customer’s account pages use at minimum the `default.xml` and `customer_account.xml` file to determine the layout of those pages.

The handle translates to a layout XML file.

Comment: hi @Shawn, still not cleared, I am loading custom sidebar menu in account dashboard, there also i used update handle, but not finding the reason behind it.

Comment: @jafarpinjar this sounds like something to be addressed in a new post

Comment: That's fine, I wanted to know the main objective of using <update handle ?

Answer (score 10):

Update is used to include a certain layout xml file.

The handle declared in the tag is included.

[Shared in Link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_upd)

You can check about layout handles [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html#handle)