# Magento 2 - what is the purpose of "update" in a layout file?

Tags: magento2, layout

I often see code like `<update handle='xy' />` in layout files.

**vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\layout\sales_email_order_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Order Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <update handle="sales_email_order_renderers"/>
    <update handle="sales_email_item_price"/>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</page>
```

What is the purpose of it?

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/236013/85907

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `update` layout directive is a way to include another layout handle in your page.
In the example you provided, in the layout `sales_email_order_items` the layout handles `sales_email_order_renderers` and `sales_email_item_price` are loaded.
This is useful if you have multiple pages with similar structures of blocks.
You out the common blocks structure in a separate layout file and you load it in multiple places.
This way you avoid configuration duplication.